# Ударение в словах "ладьи"

Tags: орфоэпия

Последнее время, смотря трансляции шахматных матчей, часто слышу в слове "ладьи" ударение на первый слог. Это жаргонизм или вариант нормы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

От шахмат отошел давно, но с шахматной тусовкой в общем-то знаком.

Никогда не слышал такого ударения. Если что-то и возникло, то совсем недавно. 
О какой-то нормативности тут говорить не приходится.

Answer (score 1):

Нормативное ударение — ладь**я**, ладь**и** (и род. ед., и им. мн.), лад**е**й, ладь**я**м. Скорее всего, л**а**дьи — профессиональное.